# Refactoring afnetworking post request to 3.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I'm getting the warnings:

`Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AFHTTPSessionManager *' from 'NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable'`

```
'POST:parameters:success:failure:' is depreceated
```

When trying to make a request with AFNetworking 3.0. I'm wondering what correct approach is to make a post request with AFNewtworking 3.0 for an app using iOS 7.0 or later. Here is my code:

```
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[SignupResponseSerializer serializer]];

    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s", kBaseURL, kRegisterURL];

    NSData *plainData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profilePicture);
    NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    if (self.firstNameField.text && self.lastNameField.text && self.passwordField.text && self.emailField.text) {
        NSDictionary *params = @{ @"first_name": self.firstNameField.text, @"last_name": self.lastNameField.text, @"password": self.passwordField.text, @"email": self.emailField.text, @"avatar_data": base64String};

        self.sessionManager = [manager POST:urlString parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
            NSDictionary *JSON = [responseObject objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *token = JSON[@"auth_token"];
            NSString *avatarURL = JSON[@"avatar_url"];


            weakSelf.credentialStore.avatarURL = avatarURL;
            weakSelf.credentialStore.authToken = token;
            weakSelf.credentialStore.firstName = self.firstNameField.text;
            weakSelf.credentialStore.lastName = self.lastNameField.text;
            weakSelf.credentialStore.email = self.emailField.text;
            weakSelf.credentialStore.password = self.passwordField.text;

            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error) {
//            if (task.isCancelled) {
//                return;
//            }
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Login Failed"];
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In AFNetworking 3.0 the POST method returns a `NSURLSessionDataTask` object with your request.
In addition now it has a `progress` parameter wich is a block called to track the progress of the request. 
 So I suggest you to change the method invocation from this:

```
self.sessionManager = [manager POST:urlString parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
...
```

to this:

```
//If you want a reference to the manager you can initialize the sessionManager var like this but it's not necessary
self.sessionManager = manager;
[manager POST:urlString parameters:params progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
        //progress block implementation
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        //success block implementation
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        //failure block implementation
    }];
```